# error while trying to pass location cordinate from a list view to a map activity

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a list view contains the locations coordinate (late,long) and i'm trying to pass them to a map activity to show it on map

this is on android studio and Kotlin

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

        val time = usersList.get(position).time
        val long:String = usersList.get(position).long
        val late :String = usersList.get(position).late
startActivity(Intent(this, MapsActivity2::class.java).putExtra("long",long).putExtra("late",late))
}
```

---

```
class MapsActivity2 : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

var long:String = intent.getStringExtra("long")
var late:String = intent.getStringExtra("late")


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2)


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(long.toDouble(), late.toDouble())
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("jh"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
}
```

> Process: com.example.firebase, PID: 32463
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebase/com.example.firebase.MapsActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3289)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3548)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2155)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.firebase.MapsActivity2.(MapsActivity2.kt:19)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
>           at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1224)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3274)

Answer (score 0):

```
var long:String = intent.getStringExtra("long")
var late:String = intent.getStringExtra("late")
```

Above code should be in onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    include code inside onCreate() also check if it contain the extra
> ```

```
oncreate(){
if(getIntent.hasExtra("long")){
var long:String = intent.getStringExtra("long")
}
if(getIntent.hasExtra("late")){
var late:String = intent.getStringExtra("late")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get intent valeu after onCreate() like this way :
i would also suggest to avoid predefined keyword like long, because long is defined as a datatype

```
var long:String = intent.getStringExtra("long")
var late:String = intent.getStringExtra("late")
```